# change video src when i click on the button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 buttons and 10 different video URL I want when I click on it change video src using jquery

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Post CODE, not only pictures

Comment: @mplungjan I well delete this post after someone answers me

Comment: No need to delete - add CODE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function(e){
  const videoSource = $(this).attr('data-src')
  $('video source').attr('src', videoSource)
  $('video')[0].load()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4">Video 1</button>
<button data-src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4">Video 2</button>
<button data-src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4">Video 3</button>

<video controls width="250">
 
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">

    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

You can create an attribute with video sources. When you click on buttons you get the attribute value and you chnage the video source. Or you could put your video sources in an array and get the index of the button clicked.

Comment: **Thanks for your answer**, your code is working but I have trayed it in a table row but not work are I should change it to a button element?

Comment: Not necessarily , you can use it with a table but you would have to change the $('button').click(function(e){ ... } by $('td').click(function(e){ ... } or $('tr').click(function(e){ ... } and put the data-src attribute into <td> or <tr>

Comment: I do it but the src not changed? Cod!    
    <tr id="link" data-src="https://cdn.fs.teachablecdn.com/Huf0ScgbQS23S0L7TvTS">
        <td id="play"></td>
        <td style="max-width: 303px;">Form (8:15)</td>
    </tr>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.max.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('tr').click(function(e){
            const videoSource = $(this).attr('data-src')
            $('video source').attr('src', videoSource)
            $('video')[0].load()
        })
    </script>

Comment: Yes like the but now the jquery selector  is tr , like this $('tr').click(function(e){ ... })

Comment: thanks, it's working this didn't work for the first time because the jquery didn't load when I change it to your link it's worked thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Let's say all of those video selector buttons have the class `.video-selector`, and the video itself has the id `#main-video`. Now, each video selector has a data attribute called `data-src` which contains the new source of the video when the button is clicked. Here is what I would do:

```js
$('.video-selector').click(function() {
  $('#main-video').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
});
```

Here is a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video-selector').click(function() {
    $('#main-video').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="video-selector" data-src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4">Video 1</button>
<button class="video-selector" data-src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4">Video 2</button>
<br>
<video id="main-video" src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4" controls></video>
```

Comment: your code is working but I have tray it in a table row but not work are I should change it to a button element?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed As long as you have the same classes/id's/data attributes, the specific element shouldn't matter.